# Trouble uploading media (images) to twilio programmable chat in react-native

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm implementing programmable-chat in react-native using the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-chat). Unfortunately, I'm stuck on being able to correctly upload messages with images to twilio.  The [twilio js documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/media-support) outlines 3 ways to create a Media Message. Sending: 1) FormData (doesn't seem applicable to me in react-native?), 2) a String, or 3) a Buffer.

I've tried many variations at this point and am stumped.  I've been all over the place with both [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) and [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) and haven't cracked it yet.

Everything I try results in failure or in a String being uploaded.  When the String is uploaded, I can complete a round trip by fetching the created Media Message, getting the the temporary url of the media attachment, manually fetching the String stored at that url, and then crafting a base64 data uri for the Image element with the fetched String. But I'm 99% sure that is 'doing it wrong'.  If I do it right, Twilio should be storing an actual image for me and giving me a temporary url that I can directly feed to my Image element, right?

To sum up: I can get a base64 encoded string to be stored in twilio, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get the image binary up there so as to be directly accessible when hitting the url it is at.

I feel like I've got to be missing something simple, but I'm out of ideas at the moment.  Is there a way to get a Buffer set up in react native? Should I be trying something with FormData?

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured this out. This was just a problem not knowing how to get the file into a buffer in react native.  I was finally able to get this working with a combination of [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) and [buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer).  The code looks something like:

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'

myMethod(twilioChannelObject, filePathString) {
  RNFS.readFile(filePath, 'base64').then((data) => {
    var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer
    data = Buffer.from(data, 'base64')

    twilioChannelObject.sendMessage({
      contentType: 'image/png',
      media: data
    }).then(id => {})
  })
}
```

This probably isn't the best practice way to solve the problem, but it got it to work for me, so moving on for now.